# How to avoid bugged animation regarding scrollView movement

Tags: android, kotlin, animation

**Issue Summary**

I am attempting to toggle the visibility of an upper view card (viewCardCashback) based on the scroll position of a ScrollView. While the logic is mostly functional, I encounter an animation glitch when I hold the scroll view at the point where the view card should either expand or collapse. I assume this happens because the code tries to both show and hide the view card simultaneously.

**Code Details**

Here is my configureViewCardAnimation() function:

```
private fun configureViewCardAnimation() {

    binding.viewCardCashback.textViewCashbackPercentages.apply {
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
                override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                    viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                    cashBackAnimation.configureHeightMetrics()
                }
            })
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        binding.scrollViewCashback.setOnScrollChangeListener { _, _, scrollY, _, _ ->
            if (scrollY == 0) {
                if (collapsedHeader) {
                    cashBackAnimation.showDescription(400)
                    collapsedHeader = false
                }
            } else {
                //Logic responsible to check if the cardView can be collapsed
                val scrollViewHeight = binding.scrollViewCashback.height
                val contentHeight = binding.constraintLayoutContent.height
                val viewCardExpandedHeight = binding.viewCardCashback.root.height
                val viewCardCollapsedHeight = DimensionUtils.pxToDp(
                    (binding.viewCardCashback.textViewCardName.marginTop +
                            binding.viewCardCashback.textViewCardName.height +
                            binding.viewCardCashback.textViewCashbackPercentages.marginTop +
                            binding.viewCardCashback.textViewCashbackPercentages.height +
                            binding.viewCardCashback.textViewCashbackPercentages.top).toFloat() + binding.viewCardCashback.textViewSeeCashbackDetails.height,
                    this
                ).toInt() + DimensionUtils.dpToPx(24, this).toInt()
                val viewCardHeightDifference = viewCardExpandedHeight - viewCardCollapsedHeight
                val isScrollable = contentHeight >
                        (scrollViewHeight + viewCardHeightDifference)

                if (!collapsedHeader && isScrollable) {
                    cashBackAnimation.hideDescription(400)
                    collapsedHeader = true
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        binding.scrollViewCashback.viewTreeObserver.addOnScrollChangedListener {
            val scrollY = binding.scrollViewCashback.scrollY
            if (scrollY == 0) {
                if (collapsedHeader) {
                    cashBackAnimation.showDescription(400)
                    collapsedHeader = false
                }
            } else {
                //Logic responsible to check if the cardView can be collapsed
                val scrollViewHeight = binding.scrollViewCashback.height
                val contentHeight = binding.constraintLayoutContent.height
                val viewCardExpandedHeight = binding.viewCardCashback.root.height
                val viewCardCollapsedHeight = DimensionUtils.pxToDp(
                    (binding.viewCardCashback.textViewCardName.marginTop +
                            binding.viewCardCashback.textViewCardName.height +
                            binding.viewCardCashback.textViewCashbackPercentages.marginTop +
                            binding.viewCardCashback.textViewCashbackPercentages.height +
                            binding.viewCardCashback.textViewCashbackPercentages.top).toFloat() + binding.viewCardCashback.textViewSeeCashbackDetails.height,
                    this
                ).toInt() + DimensionUtils.dpToPx(24, this).toInt()
                val viewCardHeightDifference = viewCardExpandedHeight - viewCardCollapsedHeight
                val isScrollable = contentHeight >
                        (scrollViewHeight + viewCardHeightDifference)

                if (!collapsedHeader && isScrollable) {
                    cashBackAnimation.hideDescription(400)
                    collapsedHeader = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, I have a CashbackAnimation class:

```
class CashbackAnimation(private val binding: ViewCardCashbackBinding, private val context: Context) {

private var cardHeight = 0
private var cardHeightCollapsed = 0
var test = true

fun configureHeightMetrics(){
    cardHeight = DimensionUtils.pxToDp(binding.cardLayout.height.toFloat(), context).toInt()
    cardHeightCollapsed = DimensionUtils.pxToDp((binding.textViewCashbackDescription.top + binding.textViewCashbackDescription.height + binding.textViewCashbackDescription.marginTop).toFloat(), context).toInt() + DimensionUtils.pxToDp(8f, context).toInt()
    println(cardHeightCollapsed)
}

fun hideDescription(time: Long) {
    binding.cardLayout.layoutHeightAnimator(
        DimensionUtils.dpToPx(cardHeight, context).toInt(),
        DimensionUtils.dpToPx(cardHeightCollapsed, context).toInt(),
        time
    )
    binding.textViewCashbackDescription.animateFade(time, 0f)
}

fun showDescription(time: Long) {
    binding.cardLayout.layoutHeightAnimator(
        DimensionUtils.dpToPx(cardHeightCollapsed, context).toInt(),
        DimensionUtils.dpToPx(cardHeight, context).toInt(),
        time
    )
    binding.textViewCashbackDescription.animateFade(time, 1f)
}
```

}

**Points to Note:**

cashBackAnimation.hideDescription(400) and cashBackAnimation.showDescription(400) are responsible for hiding and showing the view card.
collapsedHeader is a Boolean flag to keep track of the view card's state.
isScrollable is a condition to check if the view card can be collapsed based on the height metrics.

**Question**

Could anyone suggest a logical approach to fix the animation glitch when holding the scroll view at the expand/collapse point?